# Why does char overloading not work with integers and chars inside ternary expressions?

Tags: java

Code

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(returnValue('a'));
        System.out.println(returnValue(1));
        System.out.println(returnValue(true ? 'a' : 1));
        System.out.println(returnValue(false ? 'a' : 1));
    }

    public static int returnValue(int i) {return i;}

    public static char returnValue(char c) {return c;}
```

Output

```
a
1
a
```

The overloaded function works perfectly, however when a ternary is used it seems to cast both the int and the char to the char version. Why does this cast happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is defined by the JLS in [15.25. Conditional Operator ? :](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25):

> The type of a conditional expression is determined as follows:
>
> [...]
>
> If one of the operands is of type T where T is `byte`, `short`, or `char`, and the other operand is a constant expression (§15.28) of type `int` whose value is representable in type T, then the type of the conditional expression is T.

So in your case this mentioned "`T`" will be `char` because you have the constant `'a'` (which is the `char`) and the constant `1` (which is the `int`), which fits in the value range of a `char` type.